# Are Bridge AC to DC Rectifiers using thyristors still considered Linear Rectifiers considering their switching mechanism of action?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, control-system, bridge-rectifier, thyristor

While I tried not to make the title confusing, Whether if the question is about Non-Linear/Linear PSUs or just the Rectifier circuits, I believe This one covers both matters. Considering that the other parts of PSU are totally Linear in that case :

Focusing on the Rectifier part itself,
While a Thyristor uses switching mechanism and makes non-linear outputs under current loads, Do we technically assume SCR Built Rectifying bridges linear because we can sum up output equation using a linear equation ? (Graphs and equations below)

[image: We can See that while system is under load critical points are generated at the output]

[image: also the equation for output seems Linear]

We can See that while system is under load critical points are generated at the output and also the equation for output seems Linear
*"Graphs and Text source : Wikipedia:Rectifiers"*

> With supply inductance taken into account, the output voltage of the rectifier is reduced to:
>
> $$ {\displaystyle V_{\mathrm {dc} }=V_{\mathrm {av} }={\frac {3\cdot V_{\mathrm {LLpeak} }}{\pi }}\cdot \cos(\alpha +\mu )}$$
>
> The overlap angle μ is directly related to the DC current, and the
> above equation may be re-expressed as:
>
> $$ {\displaystyle {V_{\mathrm {dc} }=V_{\mathrm {av} }={\frac {3\cdot V_{\mathrm {LLpeak} }}{\pi }}\cdot \cos(\alpha )}-{6fL_{\mathrm {c}
>  }I_{\mathrm {d} }}} $$
>
> Where:
>
> Lc, the commutating inductance per phase
>
> Id, the direct current
> Considering all of the above Are PSUs with Thyristor rectifiers and all linear filter,regulation,etc parts considered Linear or Switched mode PSU ?

Comment: The term 6*f*Lc in the last equation is the "internal impedance" of the power supply. It is just multiplied by Id and show the "additional" lost of voltage vs Id.

Comment: @Antonio51 So, where would that Lead us in terms of the question ?

Comment: As other systems, the 3-phase bridge using thyristors may be considered as a "linear" block.